# Does "app lock" on the recents list keep an app alive?

Tags: task-management, background-process, recents-screen

I can't find a clear answer as to what "Lock app" on the recent apps list actually does, other than prevent apps from being killed or swiped away from the recent apps list.

Does it also prevent an app from being killed by Android? I.e. if I lock an app, will it be running indefinitely in the background, no matter what? Or could it still be killed by Android, just not by using "Clear all" on the recent apps list?

Comment: What device (model and manufacturer) and which Android version do you use? "Lock app" may be a manufacturer specific Android modification, therefore for answering your question it is important to know these details.

Comment: [Don't kill my app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://dontkillmyapp.com/&ved=2ahUKEwiSv6uTkOSAAxU-cmwGHc19DQIQFnoECBoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0ZQXLWJ_LUUdsdMcPw8uPs) has ways for various OEMs to prevent killing of apps//If locking apps would prevent Android from killing it, this method would have been mentioned there. Since it isn't mentioned, I take it that Android can kill locked apps